# Mips : "Memory Address Out Of Bounds" - Error?

Tags: mips

If I Understand well, This Program Should Print a string that entered by a User, 
As It will Store its value in `$a0`, After that print what in `$a0`

But it gives me Error - "Memory Address Out Of Bounds"

Am I understand something wrong or what ??!

Thanks In Advance

```
    .data
    .text
main:
    li $v0, 8
    syscall
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
    .end main
```

Answer (score 1):

`syscall` with `$v0 = 8` requires an address of a buffer in `$a0` and the length of the passed buffer in `$a1`.

Check if you are passing proper arguments when you call `main`.

If not, allocate a buffer (with `.space` or something) and set the parameters for the system call properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot , It worked after I Initialize a variable of space datatype , and pass its address in $a0